# Can't upload payload to my apache2 server. Pentesting exercise

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, apache, kali-linux

Im reading "Penetration Testing - A hands-on introduction to Hacking". I'm trying to figure a way out to paste a .exe to my apache2 server and later download it from my VM since these steps from the book doesn't  work:

> First, run 
>   cp chapter4example.exe /var/www
>    to copy the payload executable 
>   to the Apache directory, and then make sure the web server is started
>   wit
>   h 
>   service apache2 start
>
> root@kali:~# 
>   cp chapter4example.exe /var/www
>
> root@kali:~# 
>   service apache2 start
>
> Now switch to your Windows XP target and open Internet Explorer. 
>   Browse to 
>   http://192.168.x.x/chapter4example.exe (Yes, i do put my ip here)
>    and download the file.

But the page returns: "The page cannot be displayed"

My apache2 server is up, and the file is in /var/www.
I think i need to copy the file to another location.

Comment: Can the server be pinged? Can you reach it from localhost?

Comment: I can ping the localhost, and my Kali Linux (where the server is running)ip from the VM. @Arminius

Comment: Is /var/www/ the root of the html files? Is index.html in that location? I think you just need to figure out where the root is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it to /var/www/html/example.exe, then go to http://yourip/example.exe to download it.

Comment: I've figured it out before reading this, but thank you!. This is the solution.